# itext - XFA form fill up those fields that are not data bound to an xml element

Tags: java, pdf, itext, xfa

I have a pdf that I am able to partially fill using iText. Meaning those fields that I am able to map using guess work to an XML field I have filled up. But I am unable to fill up a few fields, because these fields don't appear to be bound to an XML output element.

My questions are:

1. Is there an easy way to understand and obtain a full blown mapping between a field in the XFA form and the exported XML element that represents it. Probably a tool?
2. How do I fill up a field which doesn't appear to be bound to an XML element. But I am able to enter data onto the field, save and open the form again to see the field still filled up. So when I looked at the raw XFA XML stream, I am able to see the data filled up sitting inside a form > subform element. Is it safe to play with data in those fields as a best practice?

I am attaching the form and the XML for reference.

[PDF Form](http://jmp.sh/42KfWhh)
[Complete XFA xml](http://jmp.sh/cAFVhIp)
[XFA Data alone](http://jmp.sh/sZ0Qz68)

The fields I am trying to fill up are at the bottom of the form. Please refer the below screenshot

[image: Fields not bound to an XML element]

**Update:**
The XDP stream has the below XML structure:

```
 .....
 ><frm:VerificationTwo dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"
/><frm:BoardResNo dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"
/><frm:AuthSigReslnDt dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"
/><frm:DesignationTwo dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"
/><frm:DINPANMembrNo dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"
/><frm:CharteredorCostorCompany dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"
/><frm:AssociateorFellow dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"
/><frm:MembershipnumberorCertificate dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"
/><frm:CrtfctNmbr dd:minOccur="0" dd:nullType="exclude"
.....
```

After I fill up the form and export the xml data via adobe reader I get the below data:

```
><frm:DesignationTwo
>DIRT</frm:DesignationTwo
><frm:DINPANMembrNo
>00000001</frm:DINPANMembrNo
><frm:CharteredorCostorCompany
>CS</frm:CharteredorCostorCompany
><frm:AssociateorFellow
>FW</frm:AssociateorFellow
><frm:MembershipnumberorCertificate
>1865</frm:MembershipnumberorCertificate
><frm:CrtfctNmbr
>12323</frm:CrtfctNmbr
```

The Elements **BoardResNo, AuthSigReslnDt** is missing in the exported the data. And the ***name*** is not present in either the dataDescription or the xml data. It only appears under

```
<form><subform name="Form32_Dtls>......<field>...<text>Sethuraman R</text>...
```

Comment: The xdp stream has a <xfa:datasets> part that consists of an <xfa:data> part and a <dd:dataDescription> part. The <dd:dataDescription> part is similar to an XSD for XML. It describes which data is expected in the <xfa:data> part. You need to examine the data description. You'll need the XFA reference to do that.

Comment: Hi Bruno.. I examined the XDP stream. I updated the question with the relevant xml stream. Even though under the dd:dataDescription the details are present, the exported XML does not have the elements after the data is filled up in the form. Also one of the elements is missing from the dataDescription and the xml data.

Comment: An element that is missing from the dataDescription and the XML data is not an interactive element, meaning: it can't be filled out. Have you examined your file in Adobe LiveCycle Designer? Maybe there's a problem with the form.